# Firebase React Native - Show Auth Error From AuthProvider

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I need to show my error message on some Text component inside `register.js`, but I don't know how to access it.
I've created AuthProvider which holds the Register/Login Functions.
Now I want to get the auth error message.
*(I deleted all the imports because it's not necessary)*

**`Register.js:`**

```
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default function Register({ navigation }) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

    const [isEmailValid, setEmailValid] = useState(true);
    const [isPasswordValid, setPasswordValid] = useState(true);

    const { register } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const handleValidEmail = (value) => {

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.header}>
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={[
                        '#1A237E',
                        '#3949AB'
                    ]}
                    style={styles.gradient}
                    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                    end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}>

                    <View style={styles.brand}>
                        <View style={styles.circle}></View>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.subtitle}>
                        <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>Register</Text>
                    </View>

                </LinearGradient>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.content}>
                <FlatInput
                    placeholder={"Full Name*"}
                    iconName={'person'} />

                <FlatInput
                    placeholder={"Email*"}
                    iconName={'mail'}
                    keyboardType={'email-address'}
                    value={email}
                    onChange={text => setEmail(text)}
                    errorMsg={"Error MEssage!"}
                    isValid={isEmailValid}
                    onEndEditing={(e) => handleValidEmail(e.nativeEvent.text)} />

                <FlatInput
                    placeholder={"Password*"}
                    iconName={'vpn-key'}
                    isPassword={true}
                    onChange={text => setPassword(text)}
                    value={password}
                    onChange={text => setPassword(text)}
                    errorMsg={"Invalid Password!"}
                    isValid={isPasswordValid} />

                <FlatInput
                    placeholder={"Group ID*"}
                    iconName={'groups'} />

                <FlatButton
                    title={'REGISTER'}
                    onPress={() => register(email, password)}
                />

                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    <View >
                        <Text style={styles.footerText}>Already have an account ?
                            <Text style={styles.clickableText} onPress={() => navigation.replace('Login')}> Login</Text>
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View >
                        <Text style={styles.footerText}>Want to create your own group ?
                            <Text style={styles.clickableText} onPress={() => alert("Coming Soon!")}> Contact Us</Text>
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

            </View>




        </View>
    )
}
```

**`AuthProvider.js:`**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children, navigation }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user,
                setUser,
                login: async (email, password) => {
                    try {
                        await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                },
                register: async (email, password) => {
                    try {
                        await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);

                    }
                },
                logout: async () => {
                    try {
                        await auth().signOut();
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                }
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

I'd like to show something like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olX8R.png)

Comment: The `login, logout, register` methods log the error. You should store them or return them and you can call these functions later as `const result = register()` where you can get the error message if it is returned.

Comment: Okay, I will try it a bit later, and return with answer.

Comment: I didn't understand how to do it, can you provide a little bit of code? @DánielBoros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the error message in the `try-catch` method like this:

```
register: async (email, password) => {
                    try {
                        await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        
                        return e.message/e
                    }
                },
```

If you call the register method you can store the returned value with hooks.

```
const registerHandler = async () => {
   const response = await register()

   if (!!response) {
      setRegisterError(response) // a way to store the API error reponse
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've got:
`LOG: {"_U": 0, "_V": 1, "_W": null, "_X": null}`

Comment: Try to add the `async await` to the registerHandler.